# How to generate classes with methods based on conditions passed by user during object instantiation using metaclasses?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I want to include certain methods in objects according to the parameters passed by the user.
like:

```py
class create_dynamic_class(type):
   pass

class foo(metaclass = create_dynamic_class):
    def __init__(self,arg):
        pass
    pass
```

if arg is 1; then include "1st" set of methods.
if arg is 2; then include "2nd" set of methods.
and so on.

I'd be able to implement this if I had a way to know the arguments passed to instantiate the objects ; inside the metaclass that will create these dynamic classes.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve. The metaclass creates the class *of all* instances; creating separate classes *per instance* misses the point of classes. While it is possible in principle, since the metaclass can control all of the class and thus its instances, this will be a lot of work, hassle and likely incompatible with any utilities expected "regular" classes. Are you looking for a factory *function* perhaps? Is there a fixed number of classes that could be created up front, or is the "set of methods" created dynamically?

Comment: A set of core functionalities are same in all classes but some classes shouldn't have some methods, i Guess i can use function decorator to dynamically create classes but i was curious if there is a way for a meta class to know with which arguments an object (whose class inherits from this metaclass) is instantiated..

Comment: I agree that it sounds like what you want is a "class factory". There are different ways of implementing them; metaclasses being one of them. You can also do it by implementing `__new___()` in a base class if the classes are in a hierarchy.